# settings all dates in english but with country specific format

Tags: asp.net, calendar, cultureinfo

I am looking for a way to set date format in either mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy . Setting culture  for my pages based on ip sets the language of asp.net calendar in local language. 
For eg: it works fine for US , Australia , Uk. But for  countries like Saudi Arabia I want my calendar to be still in English and not its local language like Arabic.

I basically want my calendar to be in English but with the correct format.

Please have a look at the code.

P.S.,
This code works fine for India where they have "en" as TwoLetterISOLanguageName. But then I realised not all countries have "en".

```
private static CultureInfo GetCultureInfo(UserSession currentUserSession, string userHostAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                string location = null;

                // use logged in user's configured location
                if (currentUserSession != null)
                {
                    location = currentUserSession.LocationString;
                }

                // fall back to IP address
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
                {
                    string code = IPToCountry.GetCountry(userHostAddress);

                    if (code != null)
                    {
                        location = Config.Users.GetCountryByCode(code);
                    }
                }

                // find english culture for country, if it exists
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
                {
                    foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "en")
                            {
                                RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
                                if (location.Contains(ri.EnglishName))
                                    return ci;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but you can set explicitly the [format for dates in a culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx).

Note that you need to clone a `CultureInfo` before being able to set the `DateTimeFormat` property.

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat APPEARS TO BE READONLY.

Comment: You understood my question great. I would like to see a way I can set the DateTimeFormat of my page.

Comment: Amazing.Thanks a lot it words. I had no clue there is a way to do it.

Comment: My calendar months were using  CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(month), month.ToString()));  Hence I had to just set the DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern , LongDatePattern , ShortTimePattern , LongTimePattern rather than the whole DateTieFormat.

Comment: @vishnu: I saw your comments just now, it looks like in the meanwhile you've figured out how to do it :)